# Creating typed shard region from untyped actory system

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-typed

I have akka cluster with untyped actor system.
Now I have to change one node to using typed actors
The question is: how can I create typed shardregion from untyped actor system?
Basically I need smth like this:

```
 import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.ClusterSharding
    ClusterSharding(untypedActorSyste).sharding.spawn(
      behavior = entityId ⇒ counter(entityId, 0),
      props = Props.empty,
      typeKey = TypeKey,
      settings = ClusterShardingSettings(system),
      maxNumberOfShards = 10,
      handOffStopMessage = GoodByeCounter)
```

All examples that I found show how to provider typed sharding based on typedActorSystem...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert typedActorSystem to untypedActorSystem using adapter import.

```
// adds support for typed actors to an untyped actor system and context
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter._
```

That adds `toUntyped` implicit extension method to typed system.

```
val typedSystem           : ActorSystem[Any]  = ActorSystem(Behavior.empty[Any], "typed-system")
implicit val untypedSystem: actor.ActorSystem = typedSystem.toUntyped
```

Check [Coexisting](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html) documentation for more details, another way is converting [Untyped to typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/coexisting.html#untyped-to-typed) system.
Choose the better one for your case.